# why crontab run my shell script successfully but failed to start my binary file program?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

i made a shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

/root/bin/mybin >> a.log
```

then I use crontab to start it at a fixed time.
The result is:

1. crontab run this script(a.log exsited and i can see the log from /var/log/cron , also it shows crontab run it)
2. but mybin is not running (mybin is a while(true) loop program)

I can run the script manually from the linux shell.

And I am sure it is not related to user access problems, since i use it as Root.

Using the command

```
strace -f -o /tmp/data.log ~/deploy/StartData.sh >> ~/script-log/data.log
```

the `strace` output contains

```
7011 write(2, "/root/deploy/StartData.sh: line "..., 80) = 80 
7011 write(2, "/root/deploy/StartData.sh: line "..., 82) = 82 
7011 exit_group(2) = ? 
7011 +++ exited with 2 +++
```

These are the last messages of `/tmp/mybin.trace`, besides these, no error message

That really bothers me, Any Suggestions are great to hear.

Comment: Are you sure `mybin` is not stopped / killed / crashed someway after being properly started by cron ?

Comment: i am sure. at least i didnt do that @Httqm

Comment: I don't know where `a.log` would be located when your script is run by `cron`. Maybe you should use an absolute path, e.g. `>> /var/log/a.log` to be sure you are looking at the right `a.log`. Does `a.log` contain anything? Does `/root/bin/mybin` print anything to stdout? You could try something like `strace -f -o /tmp/mybin.trace /root/bin/mybin >> a.log` and check `/tmp/mybin.trace`

Comment: Can you add `echo "Cron: $(date)" > /tmp/b.log` on the second line and check the result? How do you check that `mybin` is running or has been started?
Will you have a reslt when you replace `mybin` with a script that echoes to `/tmp/c.log`?

Comment: echo "Cron: $(date)" > /tmp/b.log   run good, @WalterA

Comment: @nickhuang Please [edit] your question and show the output formatted as a code block. Information in a comment is hard and may get deleted later. You have to use an additional parameter for `strace` to show the complete strings. The default setting to show the first 32 characters only doen't provide enough information. Obviously the shell prints error messages to stderr: `write(2, "/root/deploy/StartData.sh: line "..., 80)` and exits with an error indication `exit_group(2) ... +++ exited with 2`. Try `strace -f -s 1024 -o /tmp/mybin.trace /root/bin/mybin >> a.log` (strings up to 1024 chars)

Comment: Or simply use `/root/bin/mybin >> /var/log/a.log 2>&1`. This will also redirect `stderr` to your log file. You should find error messages from the shell like `/root/deploy/StartData.sh: line`...

Comment: Maybe you should show the source code of `/root/deploy/StartData.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `strace` shows that errors occur in a shell script `/root/deploy/StartData.sh`, and the shell exits with exit code 2.

`7011 write(2, "/root/deploy/StartData.sh: line "..., 80) = 80` → error message with file name and (probably) line number
`7011 exit_group(2) = ?` → program exits with code 2 (probably an error indication)

According to a [reference of shell exit codes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) this might mean

> Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)

Your program/script seems to have a problem when it's run from cron. Possible reasons might be:

- The script doesn't have an associated terminal.
- The script is run in a different directory.
- (probably more)

For a better answer follow the hints in the comments.